# App Development in a remote server

Tags: app

I am planning to develop a mobile app. But I don't want my developer team to have copies of my code in their local system (like in the case of git where you can clone the repo to your local system).
**What I need**

I need the code to be on a remote server.

The developers log in to the server and develop there (So they will not have the repo in the local system).

What is the proper solution for the above requirement? A problem I see is running the code to see the UI, since in app development we use emulators or phones to run the code.

Comment: The proper solution is to work with developers you trust.

Comment: The work flow you are proposing will annoy your developers at more than one level.  At the very least the network lag of just the mechanics of doing the work will make doing the  work unpleasant.  But the question is based on a false premise.  If the developers can work on the code on a remote system, then they can copy that code wherever they want.

Comment: If you hired me for this, I'd develop locally, and the copy paste to your system.

Comment: I’ve seen a project for a mid sized companies that insisted on this kind of thing. The devs had to fight for weeks to get sublime text installed. The work experience was horrible, and everyone tried to dodge that project. It was a total gong show, wouldn’t recommend it. If I was asked to work on something like that, I would ask for at least 3x pay or something. There’s absolutely no need to put up with this kind of thing as a dev, so they’ll just go elsewhere

Comment: Lots of people are assuming that you do not trust the developers. Can you explain more about why the code needs to be developed on a remote machine? Maybe you have a genuine reason for this, which does not involve distrust?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I am actually the developer. I was just checking the possibility of this use case as one of our clients just inquired about this usecase.

Comment: Did they give a reason why? Do you really need to be isolated from _all_ the code or just part of it?

Comment: it's mainly because there may be interns in the development team so they are not long-term employees and may leave the team in the short term and also after the development if they hire some others for maintanance, they have to share the whole source code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a desktop virtualization software like Citrix. That way their personal computers are just dumb terminals while the actual development environment runs on a server your control.

But keep in mind that:

- Developers will be far more productive when they can work on their own machines using their own tools. Which means they will get the work done in fewer hours, which reduces the whole cost of the project.
- Technical issues with this setup will lead to even more developer hours being lost.
- Some things might become difficult to test. For example, when the app responds slowly to user input, the developers won't realize that it's their app being slow and not just their internet connection to the virtualization server.
- It does not stop a determined developer from stealing any sourcecode or data. There are just too many ways to do that.
- You really shouldn't work with people you don't trust. There are far more ways in which they can sabotage your project.

For those reasons, such setups are very unusual in the software industry. The usual solution to coordinate multiple developers is to just give them all access to a common sourcecode repository and let them do commits with a sourcecode management software like Git.

Comment: I worked at a financial firm once that was set up like this. They insisted that we develop on the same hardware, software and OS that ran in production, albeit scaled-down hardware. For some reason even the network topology was something they wanted to eliminate as a variable. It wasn't developer distrust. It was to avoid running into the "it works on my machine" problem while our customers lost millions of dollars. To be honest, that was even a weak argument, if you have proper integration environments set up - which they did. Basically this is a giant PITA.

Comment: @GregBurghardt ...which means that they likely ended up with a software which makes a ton of assumptions about the environment it runs in and was never tested on anything else. Which likely causes it to crash when they make the slightest change to their infrastructure, making their fears of a super-unportable software a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: Yup. You got it. And the problems that really caused chaos in production were environmental, and never found in other environments. This has been the case every place I've worked, regardless of whether or not I'm building an application that runs on Linux using a Macbook, or working on an actual clone of a production web server.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to avoid giving developers access to the code. If they can see it they can always copy paste it.

That being said, there are *potentially* valid reasons to have code be remote. Say you trust your developers to not "steal" the code, but you don't trust that their machines have hard drives encrypted at rest and you are fearful of that kind of theft.

In cases like that, you can use services like AWS Cloud 9 or just plain ssh to have them "log in" to a remote machine. Be warned though, setting up a workflow like this takes a ton of time initially, will very likely lower your coders productivity, might cost more money for you (since you'll need to run mobile builds remotely too), and will probably be jank as all heck.

Comment: "If they can see it they can always copy paste it." <- The enterprise level desktop virtualisation solutions can be configured to stop clipboard data going from within the virtual environment to the outside e.g. [Citrix clipboard redirection](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-virtual-apps-desktops/policies/reference/ica-policy-settings.html#client-clipboard-redirection). Yes, I'm aware nothing is 100% foolproof.

Comment: Yeah even with that you can just screenshot and use image->text converters or just spend the time to manually type it out if its a small enough project (which this one probably would be). You really just need to rely on your devs, your contract, and the legal system of your country.

Answer (score 2):

You can use remote desktop systems. That's not too unusual. You don't need anything fancy here, even just setting up a box and letting the developer RDP into it from outside. This is pretty common in situations where the dev environment is difficult to duplicate, or when security is particularly important (working with health or financial data, for example).

But, realize, that

- No programmer worth their salt will find that a hindrance if they really want to steal the code
- The code probably isn't worth all that much because once the programmer understands it - they can simply recreate it.

So if your concern is preventing developers from stealing the code, you can't. And you wouldn't want to hire programmers who couldn't.